# Android AnimationDrawable memory management

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an android application & it has background animations for each activity.
I used `AnimationDrawable` `setBackgroundResource(anim.xml)` to run the animation xml files and works fine.
problem is, when I test on devices,some devices gives me an `FATAL EXEPTION` telling that 
`bitmap size exeeds VM budget(out of memory)`.

so I surfed web and found some solutions like executing `animation.setCallbacks(null)` before 
run the animation,[scaling down bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)(programmatically) and resizing drawables.
I tried them but few devices which has low heap still gives the same error.

so I want to know am I doing something wrong or missing something?
is their any other solution to this problem?

```
//animation
    private void animate() {
            imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            imgView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
            imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.level_animation);

            frameAnimation =  (AnimationDrawable) imgView.getBackground();
            if (frameAnimation.isRunning()) {
               frameAnimation.stop();
            }
            else {
               frameAnimation.stop();
               frameAnimation.start();
            }
         } 

xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true" >
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/top_anim1" android:duration="200" />
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/top_anim2" android:duration="200" />
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/top_anim3" android:duration="200" />
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/top_anim4" android:duration="200" />
       <item android:drawable="@drawable/top_anim5" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```